# Items in RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager has height not wrap_content

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

Following is the bank_card layout which I use to store layout of each item in my RecyclerView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_bank_radius"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bank_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/bank_name_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/bank_name_padding"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/bank_name_padding"
            android:textColor="@color/bankNameTitle"
            android:textSize="@dimen/bank_name" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Here is the code that I'm giving inside the Fragment's `onCreateView()` :

```
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_qr_code, container, false);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    bankList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new BankAdapter(getActivity() , bankList);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext() , 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    //dpToPx() returns the value of 8dp in px
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2 , dpToPx() , true));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    prepareBanks(); //Adding banks to the RecyclerView
    return rootView;
```

Here is the custom `GridSpacingItemDecorator` that I'm using:

```
public class GridSpacingItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

        private int spanCount;
        private int spacing;
        private boolean includeEdge;

        GridSpacingItemDecoration(int spanCount, int spacing, boolean includeEdge) {
            this.spanCount = spanCount;
            this.spacing = spacing;
            this.includeEdge = includeEdge;
        }

        @Override
        public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
            int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
            int column = position % spanCount; // item column

            if (includeEdge) {
                outRect.left = spacing - column * spacing / spanCount;
                outRect.right = (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount;

                if (position < spanCount) {
                    outRect.top = spacing;
                }
                outRect.bottom = spacing;
            } else {
                outRect.left = column * spacing / spanCount;
                outRect.right = spacing - (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount;
                if (position >= spanCount) {
                    outRect.top = spacing;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The output I expect is for each item in that GridLayout to have its height fixed to `wrap_content` . But what I get is each item in the adapter to some height, shown in the picture below:

[image: RecyclerView items not having wrap_content height]

Comment: Check the `android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"` in the xml since I don't see any view with the id `thumbnail`. Otherwise also set the height for the card view

Comment: I have removed that part of code for putting it up on StackOverflow for simplicity. It exists in the actual code.

PS. Presence of that does not matter at all.

Comment: Thanks. Setting the height fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by setting the height of the `CardView` to some height rather than `wrap_content` . Thanks to @Xixis for suggesting the answer